# List all rest service urls in spring boot cxf

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, cxf

is it possible to list all REST services when using cxf with spring-boot? I've created `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and in there I would like to list all REST service urls which were registered for my cxf servlet. I've tried to poke around `CXFServlet`, `ServletContext`, cxf `Endpoint` and cxf `Server` classes but I can't figure it out. I've also tried to review wadl generator (feature) and swagger2 feature but they create url and content when request comes. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Basically you want only the url endpoints to be displayed? not the content?

Comment: yes. just a list of something like http://localhost:8080/rest/someService

Answer (score 0):

I would scan the `@WebService` annotations on the classpath, maybe it will help you:

```
    @Autowired
    private ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider annotationScanner;

    public List<ClassDocument> generate(String basePackage) throws ClassNotFoundException {
       Set<BeanDefinition> candidateComponents = annotationScanner.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);

       List<ClassDocument> classDocuments = new ArrayList<>();

       for (BeanDefinition component : candidateComponents) {
           ClassDocument classDocument = new ClassDocument();

           Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());

           classDocument.setClassName(beanClass.getName());

           String[] baseUrl = beanClass.getAnnotation(javax.jws.WebService.class).value();

           addMethods(classDocument, beanClass, baseUrl);

           classDocuments.add(classDocument);
       }

       return classDocuments;
   }
```